# Errror al generar apk, con volley libreria

Tags: android-studio

Hola estoy desarrollando una aplicación en android estudio, cuando la quiero generar con signed apk me da este error, ya tengo mi **key generada**. Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleEsRelease]
>       Warning:com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper$1: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
>       Warning:com.android.volley.AsyncRequestLoader: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
>       Warning:com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
>       Warning:com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper$1
>       Warning:com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
>       Warning:com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper$1: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
>       Warning:com.android.volley.request.GsonRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
>       Warning:com.android.volley.request.GsonRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
>       Warning:com.android.volley.request.GsonRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
>       Warning:com.android.volley.request.GsonRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
>       Warning:there were 17 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>       Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
>       Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForEsRelease'. > Job failed, see logs for details
>       Information:BUILD FAILED in 47s
>       Information:1 error
>       Information:13 warnings

**Aqui mi gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Comment: Henrry, agrega la opción que comento en mi respuesta, vuelve a construir el proyecto y comenta resultados!.

Answer (score 2):

En realidad es una advertencia (`warning`)

> Warning:com.android.volley.error.VolleyErrorHelper$1: can't find
>   superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
>   Warning:com.android.volley.AsyncRequestLoader: can't find referenced
>   class com.google.gson.Gson Warning:Exception while processing task
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForEsRelease'. > Job
>   failed, see logs for details

Me parece que es un problema de Volley con la library de soporte, dentro de tu `proguard-rule.pro` que se encuentra en la raíz agrega para que no muestre la advertencia y puedas generar tu aplicacion:

```
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado, gracias.